# React.js this.props.user always is null in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a user delete form, which leads users to create some tickets which will be discussed inside the back-end, but as I can see that after creating a ticket I would like to change some return pattern, instead of the form I would like to return a simple text, but I cannot get my `this.props.user` inside `componentDidMount`, I grab the state from redux. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { MdDeleteSweep } from 'react-icons/md';
import {
  Container,
  Title,
  Span,
  DangerSpan,
  Desc,
  Form,
  FieldLabel,
  TextField,
  Field,
  Btn,
} from './elements/Delete';

import { delete_request } from '../../actions/auth';

class AccountDelete extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      desc: '',
      ticketCreated: false,
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.delete_request(this.state.email);
    this.setState({ ticketCreated: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (!this.props.user) return null;

    let delres = this.props.user.del_request[0];
    if (delres) {
      this.setState({ ticketCreated: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    if (!user) return null;

    return (
      <Container>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>
          <Title>
            <MdDeleteSweep /> <DangerSpan>Delete</DangerSpan> Your Account
          </Title>
          <Desc>
            You can submit your Winteka Account for deletion at any time. If you
            change your mind, you might not be able to recover it.
          </Desc>
        </div>
        {this.state.ticketCreated ? (
          <Desc>
            <DangerSpan>*</DangerSpan> You have already <b>opened a request</b>,
            please check your <b>e-mail address</b> for more information. For
            any questions please <b>Contact Us</b>.
          </Desc>
        ) : (
          <Form>
            <FieldLabel>
              <DangerSpan>*</DangerSpan> Your <Span>active email address</Span>
            </FieldLabel>
            <Field
              type="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder={user.email}
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <FieldLabel>
              <DangerSpan>*</DangerSpan> Your <Span>current password</Span>
            </FieldLabel>
            <Field
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <FieldLabel>
              Describe <Span>your problem</Span>
            </FieldLabel>
            <TextField
              rows="3"
              name="desc"
              value={this.state.desc}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <Btn onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit Application</Btn>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.auth.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { delete_request })(AccountDelete);
```

this is what `this.props` is in `componentDidMount`

[image]

Comment: what about `componentDidUpdate`? You are probably hooking up on the wrong lifeCycle here.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: I mean, what happens if you just log the `this.props.user` in componentDidUpdate? 
You got an error there, cuz `componentDidUpdate` is called every time, your component is updated.  `setState` in componentDidUpdate, will cause the component to update. So you have to add another check for your next state to be different from what you already have. So on the next `didUpdate` cycle, it is not set again.

Comment: well, I can get this.props.user inside componentDidUpdate, should I use it instead of componentDidMount?

Comment: yes. `this.props.user` is not present, when your component is mounted, but later on. Maybe because you are fetching it from the Back-End? So you should use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`here. It will give you the prevProps and prevState. Check if the current `this.props.user`is different from `prevProps.user`and then apply your changes.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Why do you need the `this.props.user` inside `componentDidMount` ?

It seems like you are unnecessary duplicating the `this.setState({ ticketCreated: true })` call inside both `componentDidMount` and
`handleClick` but it should be enough to just put it inside
`handleClick` so you can just remove the `componentDidMount` block.

If you want to introduce a *side-effect* or execute a *callback*
when `ticketCreated` becomes `true`, you should either,

a) use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook or,

b) `this.setState(newState, callbackFn)` where `callbackFn` gets executed on the state update.

**2.** The error you are getting,

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`

indicates you are on an old version (`<4.4.0`) of `react-router-dom`. [Link to relevant github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420).

You should probably update the package with the following command,

```sh
$ npm install --save react-router-dom
```